# Selenium WebDriver Java / JUnit - Getting table element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/ResetPassword/1/"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                User1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/ResetPassword/2/"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                User2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to find the `a`-tag of the tr, where the data `User2` is in the same row. I know that I can find an `a`-tag with partial link like `findElement(By.partialLinkText("/ResetPassword/"));` (the number 2 can change, so I can´t use it as seperator). But I need to seperate it by User. Is there a solution like `tr.td.text("User2") > findElement(By.partialLinkText("/ResetPassword/"));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath should do the trick for you. `.//tr[td[normalize-space(text())='User2']]//a` Just keep changing "User2" part with the desired user value.

Answer (score 0):

U can try something like this(not sure though)-

```
List<WebElement> list=table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
List<WebElement> tdvalues=null;
for(WebElement web:list){
   tdvalues=web.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
      if(tdvalues.contains("User2")){
          System.out.println(tdvalues.get(0).getText());//0th position contains the      link
      }
tdvalues.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was wondering if you could use the `.getValue()` statement with `/@a` at the end of the xpath to locate the attribute "a".
Main thing to do is find a bulletproof xpath to locate the User2 row once you have done that finding the value of "a" should be easy enough.

I hope this helps